# Items flex item is left-aligned and right-aligned, how to center it when the browser window is resized down?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have a navbar with 3 flex items as shown below, and I can't seem to figure out how to center the containers when vertically collapsed.

[image]

When I shrink the browser this is the result -

[image]

**How do I center the B logo as well as the icons container at the bottom to be vertically centered to the middle when the browser collapses?**

The code is below:

```
    <nav class = "navlinks">
    
    <img src="/bootstrap-clone/Images/bootstrap-logo-3C30FB2A16-seeklogo.com.png" alt="bootstraplogo" id="bootstraplogo">
      
    <ul class="leftbar">
        <li><a href="#"> Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Documentation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Examples</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Icons</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Themes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Expo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Blog</a></li>
      </ul>

   

    <ul class="rightbar">
      <li><a href="#"><img src="/bootstrap-clone/Images/github.svg" alt="github"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="/bootstrap-clone/Images/twitter.svg" alt="twitter"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="/bootstrap-clone/Images/slack.svg" alt="slack"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="/bootstrap-clone/Images/google.svg" alt="google"></a></li> 
      <li><a href="#"><button class="btn download">Download</button></a></li>
    </ul>

  </nav>

  </header>
```

```
    background-color: white;
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif 
}

.navlinks {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: rgb(121,82,179);
    height: auto;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .leftbar{
      padding: 10px; 
      flex-shrink: 0;
  }

  .leftbar li {
    display: inline-block; 
    padding: 5px;
  }

  .leftbar li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(236,231,244); 
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:400;
  }

  .rightbar li {
      display:inline-block;
      padding: 8px;
      padding-bottom: 0px; 
  }

  .rightbar{
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 5px; 
  }
```

Comment: There appears to be an error in your css code, some of it appears to be cut off at the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**simply using pure CSS 's media queries:**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .navlinks{
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    ul{
        margin: auto;
    }
}
```

[see an example](https://codepen.io/amans199/pen/PoZMmep)

Comment: Thank you - I'm unfamiliar with media queries which is why I didn't use it. Will read a tutorial on it. Do you by any chance have any good resources on it?

Comment: yeah ... the most awesome one is W3schools.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp